# D-Link DES-3550: can't change password

Tags: password-management, d-link

I have a D-Link DES-3550 switch, `Firmware: Build 5.00-B28`. I want to change admin password, but somehow I am unable to do this:

```
               DES-3550 Fast Ethernet Switch Command Line Interface

                        Firmware: Build 5.00-B28
      Copyright(C) 2000-2004 D-Link Corporation. All rights reserved.
username:administrator
password:****************************

DES-3550:admin#show account
Command: show account

Current Accounts:
Username         Access Level
---------------  ------------
administrator    Admin

Total Entries : 1

DES-3550:admin#config account administrator
Command: config account administrator

The username does not exist. Enter the name of an existing user.

DES-3550:admin#
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else have the same problem, the solution is to reset configuration back to system default.

Comment: One would hope there was a better way, a config reset to change a password seems wrong.  OTOH, I have used d-link equipment, I am not entirely surprised...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to totally reset it, reboot it and after the system loading is at 100% press "shift" and "6". It will launch the recovery mode and you can reset the password or the whole configuration by tapping either "reset password" or "reset factory".